# react-native-sqlite-storage is too slow to open database

Tags: android, ios, sqlite, react-native

my database takes too long to load, I need some data that's in there in the first view, but when it loads and it tries to call the db it isn't opened yet.
Is it possible to open the database sooner as AsyncStorage does, maybe via native code?
I know that I can show SplashScreen for much longer time, but my best solution would be to open the database before.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: My suggestion, use https://realm.io/blog/introducing-realm-react-native/ for database operations

Comment: that's actually what I did, now it's much faster